# mac m1 Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi jupyter notebook installation

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

I'm trying to install jupyter
Here is the error code returned by the terminal
The terminal failed to build wheel for argon2-cffi
And my pip is up to date

````
  Building wheel for argon2-cffi (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/d4/c4921t512mzg2r8k08rpp2m00000gn/T/tmp3ghdrsdd
       cwd: /private/var/folders/d4/c4921t512mzg2r8k08rpp2m00000gn/T/pip-install-jcd5rmfw/argon2-cffi_820a55df5940451a983e99ca7f47a25b
  Complete output (24 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/low_level.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_ffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_password_hasher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_legacy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/extras
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/extras/libargon2
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/extras/libargon2/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/extras/libargon2/src/blake2
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/argon2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/extras/libargon2/src/argon2.o
  xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (no such file)).
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi 
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects```
````